# How To Catch if in all possible case?

Tags: java, regex

I wish to find a regex which matches all combination of the word `if`. So the valid ones are :

`iF, IF , If and if`

I have a regex here: `[iIfF]*`

Eventhough it is matching what I want, it is matching the word `Fi` and other such combinations too.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: have you considered matching case-insensitive? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE

Comment: Because you are matching any combination of the letters i, I, f, or F. Thus, it will match iiiiiiiiiiiif, iffffffFFFFff and ifififififififif.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to be using Java, you'd want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("if", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: The output should be something like (i|I)(f|F) although in such a simple case, you could really just test for the four different results.

Answer (score 3):

```
[iI][fF]
```

Everything in the brackets in any combination will be allowed.

**EDIT** Java allows for case insensitive RegEx

```
"(?i)if"
```

would suffice

Comment: This is not feasible for more complex strings. That's what the case-insensitive modifier is for.

Answer (score 3):

This will match `iF, IF , If and if`

```
[iI][fF]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want something like:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("if", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

This is the normal way to make your patterns case insensitive in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your regex case insensitive with the `(?i)` flag:

```
String regex = "(?i)if";
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try using this:</strike>

```
/if/i
```

The `i` at the end makes the match case-insensitive.

Sorry -- had my Perl hat on. You can use a case-insensitive pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("if", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

or, more tersely:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)if");
```

Comment: @Benj - Right you are. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a regex, but why don't you use [equalsIgnoreCase(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
boolean b = yourString.equalsIgnoreCase("if");
```

Comment: ...Why didn't I think of that.